# Python line numbers with xgettext

Tags: python, gettext, xgettext

It is my understanding that most uses of `gettext` with Python files use some nice Python library/utility to create the `.pot` files.  I am in an odd circumstance where I need to use the Python mode of `xgettext` to extract not only strings, but the line number and the filename.  All examples of such I have seen have used processes other than `xgettext`.

How can I add line number and filename info with Python mode of `xgettext`?

In C-mode it would look like:

```
#line 8 "superior_science.c"
_("Facial hair has been shown to improve intelligence by a factor of 5.");
```

In Python, what would the input file need to look like? (Note: the code only needs to work for `xgettext`, not any compiler or interpreter.)

Comment: xgettext adds this to the po files automatically i think

Comment: There is no way to hard-code the line numbers?  These files aren't actually going to originate in the file that is passed to xgettext, and I need to explicitly set that.

Comment: you could make your own file parser that reads the comment line above or something... po files are not complicated at all

Comment: That may be a reasonable approach.  I want to see if there is any good way to handle quotes within gettext strings *without* resorting to making a translator look at an escaped character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xgettext to extract comments from the line above the gettext call. These comments go into the .pot and .po files, so the translator can see them.

You simply choose a prefix character for comments you want to translate, prefix your comments with it, and call xgettext with the `-c` option and your character prefix.

So for example, if you use the prefix `~`, your line above could be

```
#~ line 8 "superior_science.c"
_("Facial hair has been shown to improve intelligence by a factor of 5.")
```

and then when you call xgettext as

```
xgettext -c~ [...]
```

it will automatically add the comment `~ line 8 "superior_science.c"` to your .pot file.

In the .pot file, these comments appear as something like the following:

```
#. ~ line 8 "superior_science.c"
msgid "Facial hair has been shown to improve intelligence by a factor of 5."
msgstr ""
```

If you want to extract all comments, not just those with a certain prefix, just leave the prefix out and call `xgettext -c`.

As for your use case you probably don't want the *actual* line numbers in there, you'll also need to use the `--no-location` flag.

So, simplest solution: add comments with the line number above your extractable strings, then call xgettext as

```
xgettext -c --no-location [...]
```

Comment: Incredible!  I had assumed it wasn't doable after not getting an immediate response.  Thank you!